# Jasmine test a method that sets variables described in a different method

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

New to angular and Jasmine. I have a `save()` method that I want to unit test in my controller I am testing. It sets some variables that were defined when I previously did a `select()` (which is basically the method called when a row is clicked on my UI). Here's the snippet:

```
function select(row){

        vm.selected.row = row;
        vm.someValue = false;
}
```

And now I have the function `save()`

```
function save(){

        if(vm.selected.row == 1)
        { 
            //doSomething 
        }
        vm.someSaveValue = vm.someValue; // assigning vm.someSaveValue to the value I set to false in select method above
}
```

But if I write Unit test for Save() method, I won't have access to the variables I created in the `select()` method. Any clue how to achieve that ? 
Here is my sample test snippet

```
describe('Test someValue setting', function(){
            it('test someValues', function (done) {
                vm.save().then(function () {
                    spyOn(vm.select)  // maybe this way, but how to access the variables this sets to ??????

                    expect(vm.someValue).toEqual('true');
                });
                scope.$apply();
                done();
            });

        });
```

Obviously, when I run my test, it reaches my main controller method `save()` but error out saying that `It vm.selected.row is undefined` and fails. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not really a unit test. You should be testing the `save()` function in isolation. If it is dependent on some values from another function then it is no longer a unit test.

To test inside your if block you should set the value of `vm.selected.row` manually. Same goes for `vm.someValue`. You should be testing that the value of `vm.SomeSaveValue` is what you are expecting, not what the value of `vm.someValue` is. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
it('should set the value of vm.SomeSaveValue to false', function() {
    vm.someSaveValue = true;
    vm.someValue = false;
    vm.selected.row = 2;

    vm.save()

    expect(vm.SomeSaveValue).toEqual(false);
}
```

or to test something inside your `if` block you would do something like:

```
it('should do something', function() {
    vm.selected.row = 1;

    vm.save();

    expect('something done in if block').toBe('some value');
}
```

This removes any dependency on your select function from your test. If your save function actually makes a call to `select()` then you should use a spy and the `and.CallFake()` option.

Answer (score 0):

Call the other method before calling save.

```
describe('Test someValue setting', function(){
        it('test someValues', function (done) {
            vm.select(1);
            vm.save().then(function () {
                spyOn(vm.select)  // maybe this way, but how to access the variables this sets to ??????

                expect(vm.someValue).toEqual('true');
            });
            scope.$apply();
            done();
        });

    });
```

Comment: This won't work, since the `vm.select(1)` is executed but when you are testing in the `it(....)` for save(), it doesn't have access to the variables.

Comment: if it is global variable it should be accessable. else create spy for that method then spyOn(test, "save"); and return the result.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? Or provide a snippet of it ?

Comment: spyOn(foo, "getBar").and.callFake(function() {
      return 1001;
    });
    it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    expect(foo.getBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

i mean fake the call. But still i am not sure why you are not able to access those variable in save function.

Comment: Note, both methods are separated and in my `save()` method I am not calling `select()` method.

Comment: so if both are separate and it not global variable how can save access those ??

Comment: But then if I set everything on global scope then it's really not a good practice right ?

Comment: yes right, but if you want to access that variable in some other method you either need to pass it or set globally to be accessible.